# D3 draw children paths under parents

Tags: d3.js, svg

```js
var data = [{
parent: {path: "M80 0 L500 0 L500 40 L80 40 Z", color: "red"},
children: {
   a: {path: "M80 0 L220 0 L220 40 L80 40 Z"},
   b: {path: "M220 0 L360 0 L360 40 L220 40 Z"},
   c: {path: "M360 0 L500 0 L500 40 L360 40 Z"}
    }
},
{
parent: {path: "M80 40 L500 40 L500 80 L80 80 Z", color: "green"},
children: {
  a: {path: "M80 40 L220 40 L220 80 L80 80 Z"},
  b: {path: "M220 40 L360 40 L360 80 L220 80 Z"},
  c: {path: "M360 40 L500 40 L500 80 L360 80 Z"}
  }
},
]

var parents = d3.select("svg")
     .selectAll("g")
     .data(data)
     .enter().append("g");

parents.append("path")
  .attr("d", function (d) { return d.parent.path; })
  .style("fill", function(d) {return d.parent.color} );
```

What is the best way to draw children paths under the parent paths like below? I wonder if there is any d3 idiomatic way to do this.

```
<svg>
   <g><path d="M80 0 L500 0 L500 40 L80 40 Z" style="fill: red;"></path>
        <g>
             child a
             child b
             child c
        </g>
   </g>
   <g><path d="M80 40 L500 40 L500 80 L80 80 Z" style="fill: green;"></path>
        <g>
             child a
             child b
             child c
        </g>
   </g>
</svg>
```

I created a jsfiddle sample for help. https://jsfiddle.net/kvslee/vkmpyjub/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're asking is complicated because, in D3, the `data` function accepts three things: an **array**, a function or nothing. The easier solution is changing the data structure... however, I'll propose a solution using exactly your data structure.

For that to work, in the children's paths, I had to convert that object in an array with this ugly data join:

```
var children = childrenGroup.selectAll("foo")
    .data(function(d) {
        var childrenData = [];
        for (var key in d.children) {
            childrenData.push({
                path: d.children[key].path
            })
        };
        return childrenData
    })
    .enter()
    .append("path");
```

Here is the whole code, check the console for the SVG:

```js
var data = [{
    parent: {
      path: "M80 0 L500 0 L500 40 L80 40 Z",
      color: "red"
    },
    children: {
      a: {
        path: "M80 0 L220 0 L220 40 L80 40 Z"
      },
      b: {
        path: "M220 0 L360 0 L360 40 L220 40 Z"
      },
      c: {
        path: "M360 0 L500 0 L500 40 L360 40 Z"
      }
    }
  },

  {
    parent: {
      path: "M80 40 L500 40 L500 80 L80 80 Z",
      color: "green"
    },
    children: {
      a: {
        path: "M80 40 L220 40 L220 80 L80 80 Z"
      },
      b: {
        path: "M220 40 L360 40 L360 80 L220 80 Z"
      },
      c: {
        path: "M360 40 L500 40 L500 80 L360 80 Z"
      }
    }
  },
];

var svg = d3.select("svg");

var parents = svg.selectAll("foo")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .style("fill", function(d) {
    return d.parent.color
  });

parents.append("path")
  .attr("d", function(d) {
    return d.parent.path;
  });

var childrenGroup = parents.selectAll("foo")
  .data(function(d) {
    return [d]
  })
  .enter()
  .append("g");

var children = childrenGroup.selectAll("foo")
  .data(function(d) {
    var childrenData = [];
    for (var key in d.children) {
      childrenData.push({
        path: d.children[key].path
      })
    };
    return childrenData
  })
  .enter()
  .append("path");

children.attr("d", function(d) {
  return d.path;
})

var mySVG = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(svg.node());
console.log(mySVG)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

This is the result of that `console.log` with a proper indentation:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g style="fill: red;">
        <path d="M80 0 L500 0 L500 40 L80 40 Z" />
        <g>
            <path d="M80 0 L220 0 L220 40 L80 40 Z" />
            <path d="M220 0 L360 0 L360 40 L220 40 Z" />
            <path d="M360 0 L500 0 L500 40 L360 40 Z" />
        </g>
    </g>
    <g style="fill: green;">
        <path d="M80 40 L500 40 L500 80 L80 80 Z" />
        <g>
            <path d="M80 40 L220 40 L220 80 L80 80 Z" />
            <path d="M220 40 L360 40 L360 80 L220 80 Z" />
            <path d="M360 40 L500 40 L500 80 L360 80 Z" />
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

PS: I moved the style to the parent group.

Comment: Your solution works great! One question? `var childrenGroup = parents.selectAll("foo")
  .data(function(d) {
    return [d]
  })
  .enter()
  .append("g"); ` Can you think if this can be shorten to `var childrenGroup = parents.append("foo")` I am just curious if you have a special reason. Thanks much.

Comment: Nope. There is no `foo` tag neither in HTML nor SVG. That's what we call an "enter" selection. Please Google *D3 enter selection*, there are lots of good tutorials about it. Also, have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/d3.js/2135/selections/16948/the-role-of-placeholders-in-enter-selections#t=201705180646000881786

Comment: I know that foo does not exit. My question was that the section may be abbreviated to one line because childrenGroup already inherits parents data so that we may not need to re-enter data.

Comment: No, it can't. It in fact inherits the data; however, it's an enter selection.